# Mimicking radio button logic

Tags: c#, radio-button

I need to mimic the radio-buttons logic (2 buttons/events) in C# with these rules:

1. Mutually exclusive
2. Once either is selected, the user can not reset it- as in the user can't assert the event again to delete it. He has to keep switching between the 2 events to change anything. He can't undo whatever the event did.

To elaborate: say I have 2 events A & B that are tied to keyboard buttons A & B.

```
      private void eventA()
      {
      //// draws red circle at current mouse position
      }

      private void eventB()
      {
      //// draws blue circle at current mouse position
      }

       private void Handlekeyboard()
      {
        keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Key.A) && lastKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(Key.A))
        {
            EventA_bool = true;
            lastKeyboardState = keyboardState;
        }
        if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Key.B) && lastKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(Key.B))
        {
            EventB_bool = true;
            lastKeyboardState = keyboardState;
        }
      }

      protected override OnMouseMove (MouseButtonEventArgs e)

      {
        if(EventA_bool)
          {
           EventA ();
          }
        else if(EventB_bool)
          {
            EventB ();
          }
      }
```

So if I click keyboard button "A", a red circle will follow mouse position. Then if I click "B", the red circle should stop wherever the last position was before the "B" click and now blue circle follow mouse movement. And the converse is true, if I start with button "B", blue circle follows. Then if I click "A", red circle follows and blue circle stops but doesn't disappear. I am not sure how to do event A without deleting or erasing event B.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a toggle button instead of the regular button if you want to have control over the button's current click state.

If I understand your problem correctly, you'll want to set up A & B as two toggle buttons and create two bool properties w/ dependency property info in your view model for binding each toggle button's IsChecked property.  Then, in the property changed event of each dependency property, you can define the behavior you're looking for based on whether the button is clicked or not.